# Ожидание потока и присоединение потока <thread>. Где параллелизм?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь вникнуть в потоки и не могу понять несколько вещей:

1. Если мы создали поток и присоединились к нему, т.е. создающий поток не продолжится, пока не завершится тот, к которому присоединились, то в чём здесь параллелизм? По сути потоки по очереди выполняют свои подпрограммы?
2. Зачем нужны "фоновые" потоки, если мы после отсоединения никак не можем к нему обратиться? Т.е. он может выполнять довольно узкие работы, которые не требует подачи или "отдачи" каких-либо данный?
3. Из второго вытекает то, что большинство потоков будет таких, к которым нужно присоединяться, т.е. они выполняются последовательно. Тогда где параллелизм?

Я понимаю, что упускаю какую-то явную и очень важную деталь, объясните, пожалуйста, какую?
Спасибо!

Comment: Вроде этот вопрос уже задавался. Если кратко - можно создать сотню потоков и ждать всех. С отсоединенными потоками можно работать через различные средства IPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот допустим у вас задача умножить на 2 каждое число в массиве из 1000 элементов. Вы создаете поток, давая ему на обработку элементы с индексами 1...500, а в главном потоке начинаете обрабатываете элементы с индексами 501...1000. После того, как главный поток закончил обрабатывать свою часть задания, он вызывает `join` и начинает ждать второй поток (который к этому моменту тоже уже наверняка закончил обрабатывать свою часть задания). Так вот, выходит что пока первый поток обрабатывал свою половину задания, второй поток - обрабатывал вторую, т.е. два потока работали *параллельно*. Суть в том, что потоки большую часть времени проводят в выполнении заданий, а не в ожидании завершения чего-то там. Если же во второй поток отправить на обработку все 1000 элементов, и в главном сразу начать его ждать, то никакого параллелизма не будет.

Comment: Ааа, т.е. в момент создания потока он уже начал выполнять возложенную на него функцию, а в момент `join` он мог выполнение ещё не закончить, и тогда главный поток будет его ждать, но "недолго", а мог закончить и тогда ждать его не нужно.

А если главный поток должен считывать информацию с консоли и передавать во второй поток, то возможно ли "додавать" ему новую информацию во время выполнения? Поток завершится, если данные для обработки кончатся, но главный поток ещё будет иметь возможность принять информацию или он будет ждать "присоединения"?

Comment: @Sotnik Ну это вопрос организации обработки заданий в фоновом потоке. Можно сделать чтобы он получал "задания" и ждал исполнял их по получении, и выходил только при получении задания на выход.